# How do I parse Merriam-Webster api's JSON response?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, jsonparser

I'm trying to make a chrome extension that searches words from the web in the Merriam-Webster dictionary, so I received an API key and started programming my `background.js` for a `contextMenu`.

Here is an example of a response:
https://dictionaryapi.com/products/api-collegiate-dictionary

Under is a sample code I've created to get the stems of the word selected.

#### In my `manifest.json`:

```
"permissions": [
     "contextmenus":,
     "https://dictionaryapi.com/"
]
```

#### In my `background.js`:

```
const apikey = "my_api_key";
var url = "";

function parse(json) {
    var script = JSON.parse(json);
    alert(script.stems.toString())
}

function searchText(info) {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    url = "https://dictionaryapi.com/api/v3/references/collegiate/json/"+info.selectionText+"?key="+apikey;
    
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true)
    parse(xmlhttp.responseText)
}

chrome.contextMenus.create({
    title: 'Search "%s" in Dictionary',
    contexts: ['selection'],
    onclick: searchText
})
```

#### Result:

In this image I created an item in the contextMenu.

[image]

However, when I press it, it gives me this error:

```
Error in event handler: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
```

It shows that `JSON.parse(json)` in the function `parse(json)` caused the error.

I suspect it is because of the brackets surrounding the whole JSON text.
Is there a way to get the `stems` item from the text, or else a way to remove the brackets?

Comment: Please post actual JSON (or any response, even as text) you've received yourself from the API.

Comment: You may see [here](https://dictionaryapi.com/products/api-collegiate-dictionary) for an example response, which from I seems appropriate for building the code.

Comment: That example is not a valid JSON as it lacks the surrounding `{` and `}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example response shown [here](https://dictionaryapi.com/products/api-collegiate-dictionary) is not actually JSON, because it's missing the opening and closing braces.  You will have to add the braces yourself; for example:

Change this:

```js
parse(xmlhttp.responseText)
```

To this:

```js
parse('{' + xmlhttp.responseText +'}')
```

I wish all questions posted by users with `1` reputation were as well written and formatted as yours, by the way.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was confused a lot since the JSON format wasn't that familiar to me.

Comment: Glad to help.  If you liked my answer you can award me Best Answer by clicking the green checkmark at the top left of my post.